# Remove Streams from CombineLatestStream - RxDart

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, rxdart, flutter-streambuilder

I am using:

- Provider Package - StreamProvider
- RxDart package - CombineLatestStream
- Firebase Realtime Database - onValue Stream

### Code Functionality

1. I get all my `FrediUserGroup` data from a provider declared at the beginning of the app.

```dart
 var userGroups = Provider.of<List<FrediUserGroup>?>(context);
 FrediUserGroup group = userGroups![widget.groupIndex];
```

2. I use the `group.participantsIds` property, that is constantly updated if some id is added/deleted from the database, as an argument for the stream in question:

```dart
    StreamBuilder(
        stream: getGroupParticipantsDB(group.participantsIds),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> 
            participantDataSnapshot) {
            return MyWidgets() //any widget to display data
        });
```

3. Using `rxDart`, the data from those participants is loaded into a `CombineLatestStream`

```dart
 Stream<List<FrediUser>>? getGroupParticipantsDB(List<String>? participantIds) {
    List<Stream<FrediUser>> streams = [];
    
    participantIds?.forEach((id) {
       var streamToAdd = dbQuery(2, 'users', id).onValue.map((event) => 
       FrediUser.fromMap(event.snapshot.value as Map));
       streams.add(streamToAdd);
    });
    
    return CombineLatestStream.list(streams);}
```

### Problem

- When I delete all participants in the database, `group.participantIds` is changed and updated to empty [].
- The streambuilder gets called again, and the stream `getGroupParticipantsDB(group.participantsIds)` gets called again.
- However, the `CombineLatestStream` still has the old streams (old participants that are now deleted, which don't even appear in the `group.participantIds`), eventhough the `streams` list is empty this time around.

### Question

How can I delete/reset the `CombineLatestStream` before calling `CombineLatestStream.list(streams)` again? Because it is storing the old streams which I no longer need. As it is an immutable list, I cannot clear() it.

Comment: Could you provide a code where you listen the given stream?

Comment: @AlexShinkevich see updated answer. The problem also happens when listening to Combine Latest Stream with provider package. It seems to not mtter from where I am listening to them, onluy that I need to clear/reset it.

Comment: As I see you don't use participantIdsSnapshot. I guess you always provide the same data to getGroupParticipantsDB.
I guess you should actual list of id from participantIdsSnapshot

Comment: You are correct, I was not using the snapshot. That code should have been deleted, because it was for testing. The `group.participantsIds` comes from a `Provider`, which gets updated every time the database gets updated (coming from a stream). I have updated the code

Comment: @AlexShinkevich I have tested if the `group.participantsIds` gets updated, and it does. Yet the `CombineLatestStream` has the same list of streams, always, unless I hot restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs rxdart

https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html

> If the provided streams is empty, the resulting sequence completes
> immediately without emitting any items and without any calls to the
> combiner function.

and according to the docs of flutter

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

> The data and error fields of snapshots produced are only changed when
> the state is ConnectionState.active.

I assume that when you have an empty list of id, CombineLatestStream has an empty list of streams and closes the stream immediately. Since the stream is closed, StreamBuilder doesn't provider new data.

To rerender your widget with empty array of users try to use a condition like this:

```
if (ids.isEmpty) {
  return Stream.value([]);
}
```

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS! returning an alternate empty stream was the answer, not clearing the CombineLatestStream! Thank you very much!!!!!